# Knockout JS: Bind Json Return Data From c# bind with HTML

Tags: c#, json, knockout.js

I got the response and json array but did not map on html Tag.. please help here's my code

C# Code

```
public JsonResult ShowEmpData() 
{
    var data = new DAL.ManageEmployee().ShowEmp();
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

HTML and JSCode

```
<div class="container">
    <ul data-bind="foreach:dat">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text:strAddress"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dat;
        $.getJSON("@Url.Action("../Employee/ShowEmpData")")
        .done(function (data)
        {
            dat = JSON.stringify(data);
            console.log(dat);
            alert(dat);
            ko.applyBindings(dat);
        })
            .fail(function (jqxhr, txtsts, err) { alert("fail: " + err); });

    });
</script>
```

When I use Json.strinfy(data[image])

Comment: What is the response you're getting from server? Add it to the question.

Comment: ok see the picture..

Answer (score 0):

The only issue in your code is **You're converting JSON to string**:

```
dat = JSON.stringify(data); //don't do it
```

instead, simply assign `data` to `dat`:

```
dat = data;  //because you're already getting JSON from server
```

Comment: This don't work for mee
when i use dat = data; its show's 
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: Try this `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));`. Because the only issue I could possibly think that the `ko.applyBindings` is not receiving a proper JSON object.

Comment: No This not work for me when i use JSON.parse then it convert back to [object Object],..

Comment: i am finding the answer from 3 days can u please check my binding with HTML is this ok